# Rails: How do I create a db level index to support 'validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: [:flaggable_id, :flaggable_type]'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, indexing

I'm using a very common polymorphic association allowing users to flag a `Problem`, or flag a `Solution` etc. Here's the basic setup:

```rb
class Flag < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :flaggable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user

  # Ensures a user can only flag the same object once.
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: [:flaggable_id, :flaggable_type]
end
```

This line: `validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, scope: [:flaggable_id, :flaggable_type]` successfully restricts a user from flagging the same object twice.

Now I'd like to add the same constraint at database level to support this restriction.

The indexes that were added automatically when creating the table:

```rb
t.index ["flaggable_type", "flaggable_id"], name: "index_flags_on_flaggable_type_and_flaggable_id"
t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_flags_on_user_id"
```

I'm fairly certain neither of these do what I'm looking for.

How do I create a migration that will add a unique constraint ensuring users can only flag the same object once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add a unique constraint with `user_id` in it too:

Add a migration e.g. `rails g migration add_unique_index_to_users_flags`

And add the following line to in the migration file

```
  add_index :flags, %i[user_id flaggable_type flaggable_id], unique: true
```

Run `rails db:migrate` and it should work fine.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Now that I have three indexes, (the two originals ones in my question, and now this one), are any of these redundant? Do I need all of them?

Comment: No, only the one you created here. You should remove the others with a new migration: `remove_index :flags, name: 'index_flags_on_user_id_and_flaggable_type_and_flaggable_id'`.

Comment: I didn't check if this was the actual name, so make sure the find the name, If you use Postgres, then you can use `psql` to find the name of in de index in your table.